# I wanna know how the below code will work for a sub page in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The url where the code works fine

www.domainname.com/checkout

```
<?php if (is_page('checkout') ) { ?>
My code for checkout page  
<?php } ?>
```

the url where i'm facing issue with this code

www.domainname.com/checkout/order-recieved

```
<?php if (is_page('order-recieved') ) { ?>
My code for order-recieved 
<?php } ?>
```

i even tried

```
<?php if (is_page('checkout/order-recieved') ) { ?>
My code for order-recieved 
<?php } ?>
```

any suggestions? is this some kinda syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) that woocommerce provides, you should be able to do this with [is_wc_endpoint_url](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_wc_endpoint_url.html).

In Example:

```
if (function_exists('is_wc_endpoint_url')) {
    if(is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')) {
        // Run your code
    }
}
```

`function_exists` is used to verify that Woocommerce is enabled. The function [is_plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) could be used instead, however according to WordPress the function is "*only available from within the admin pages*" and would require including `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` in order for it to work on the front end.

You could also clean up the checkout if statement by using [is_checkout](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_checkout.html) instead of `is_page('checkout')`

Comment: never mind that... it got copied from my notepad. it's the same ' in my editor code. i wanna know how the slug will  be if the page is like checkout/order-recieved

Comment: Hey Charles it works fine now, i used your last suggestion (i.e) instead of is_page('checkout') i replaced it with is_checkout('order-received'), and wallah!!!.... Thanks man Appreciate your help.... :)